# How to letsencrypt flask application running on docker and gunicorn as a webserver..?

Tags: docker, nginx, lets-encrypt

I am trying to get SSL for my site, i have try to do it with many tutorial i have follows, and yeah i can do it, but many of these tutorial mostly using nginx as a webserver.
But.. now i want to get SSL for my site which running on docker and gunicorn as a webserver. 
I have follows many tutorials and source, but i can't do it.
and so.. how to do that.?, 
any source example or tutorials will be very appreciated...?
this my **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM python:3.6.5-stretch

MAINTAINER Irwan Santosa

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev

ENV INSTALL_PATH_DOCKER /web_app_docker

RUN mkdir -p $INSTALL_PATH_DOCKER

WORKDIR $INSTALL_PATH_DOCKER

COPY requirements.txt requirements_docker.txt

RUN pip install -r requirements_docker.txt

COPY . .

CMD gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:80 --access-logfile - "web_app.app:create_app()"
```

and this is my **docker-compose.yml** :

```
version: '3'

services:
  web_app_docker:
    build: .
    command: >
      gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:80
      --access-logfile -
      --reload
      "web_app.app:create_app()"

    volumes:
      - '.:/web_app_docker'

    ports:
      - '9999:80'

  service_postgresql_docker:
    image: 'postgres:9.6'

    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: 'irwan'
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: '12345'

    volumes:
      - '/var/lib/postgresql/data'

    ports:
      - '5435:5432'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[SOLVED]** i am do it with nginx reverse proxy. 
This my **default** file config at /etc/nginx/sites-available/**default**

```
server
{
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  server_name irwan.trinanda.tk;
  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server
{
  listen 443 ssl;
  listen [::]:443 ssl;
  server_name irwan.trinanda.tk;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/irwan.trinanda.tk/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/irwan.trinanda.tk/privkey.pem;
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/live/irwan.trinanda.tk/dhparams.pem;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

  location /.well-known
  {
    root /var/www/ssl/website1/;
  }

  location /
  {
    include proxy.conf;
    proxy_pass http://128.199.80.54:9999/;
  }
}
```

i have follow this tutorial, and yea.. i got it: 
https://www.guyatic.net/2017/05/09/configuring-ssl-letsencrypt-certbot-nginx-reverse-proxy-nat/ 
many thanks to who was wrote that.

Comment: Bummer. I was hoping you had resolved without using nginx. Does that mean there is no way to enable ssl on docker/gunicon without having to set up nginx? 
The link is also now unavailable so double bummer